# Sum first three (or four) non blank cells in a row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a box office sheet. It's far more complex than this, but basically it is:

[image]

I want to sum only the first 3 days gross of each film (opening weekend), jumping the blank cells. To make it a little more complicated, I want to add the possibility for a 4 or 5-day opening weekend. There could be a column where I'd enter the number of days.

I'm only familiarized with basic functions and a few complex ones. Is it possible to keep it simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I usually try to accomplish formula results without **array formulas**¹, I don't know any way to accomplish this without one.

In E4 as an array formula¹:

```
=SUM(INDEX(F4:L4, 0, MATCH(1,SIGN(LEN(F4:L4)),0)):
     INDEX(F4:L4, 0, MATCH(1,SIGN(LEN(F4:L4)),0)+D4-1))
```

Fill down as necessary. Some [IFERROR functionality](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) could wrap around that for circumstanses where the # of days and available columns are mismatched.

[image: sum_by_days]

---

¹ <sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula. Try and reduce your full-column references to ranges more closely representing the extents of your actual data. Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum. See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for more information.</sub>